# Expo App rejected by Apple due to using "public APIs with Notification Center"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, app-store

I got an app (build with Expo/ReactNative) in the Apple AppStore (and Google PlayStore) that has been rejected a whole year after it has been published and being accepted by Apple.

Apple's message is the following:

> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> We still found that your app **uses public APIs with Notification Center** in a manner not prescribed by Apple, which is not in compliance with the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In particular, section 3.3.1 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement specifies:
>
> "Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs."
>
> While **your app may use public APIs such as local notifications to display content in Notification Center**, the content displayed is not consistent with the purpose of Notification Center.

**Problem is: The app isn't using Notification Center at all.**

I already search the whole code for something related to Notification Center or something similar, but even a fulltext search for `notif` returns no result.

Those are the dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-av": "^10.1.3",
    "expo-brightness": "^10.0.3",
    "expo-keep-awake": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-localization": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.0.3",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
```

Do you guys see any package that could possibly contain something or do you know anything that would make Apple giue the statement written above? I have no clue what to do to bring the app back into the AppStore.

The only packages coming remotely near to the Notification Center are `expo-brightness` and `expo-keep-awake`, but I didn't find any hint in the web that those two packages have been rejected before. And both packages are kinda crucial for the app.

Maybe you can help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's probably a mistake. Appeal the decision with your findings